# Не понимаю как работает fetch()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
let response = await fetch("<?= home_url('/wp-content/themes/blabla/pages/business/sendmail.php') ?>", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
});
```

пытаюсь обратится к этому файлу но вместо "/blabla/business/sendmail.php" он переходит в "blabla/business/?name=1&type=1&phone=&email=&title=&description=#" почему так?

Comment: видимо проблема в маршрутизации wordpress?

Comment: и что возвращает сама home_url в текущем коде?

Comment: А сам fetch тут не при чём

Comment: Вангую, что sendmail.php делает редирект